# F# convention for brace placement

Tags: coding-standards, f#

Is there a generally accepted convention for brace placement in F#? I found some examples in the documentation, but they didn't seem to be consistent with each other. In particular, and to take an actual example, is there a consensus as to which is better, this

```
seq {
    for polarity, a in Set.filter (fun (polarity, _) -> polarity) c do
    let c = Set.remove (polarity, a) c
    for a0, a1 in orientations (eqn a) do
    for polarity, b in Set.filter (fun (polarity, _) -> polarity) c do
    let c = Set.remove (polarity, b) c
    for b0, b1 in orientations (eqn b) do
    match unify a0 b0 with
    | None ->
        ()
    | Some m ->
        yield 
            c                                            
            |> Set.add (true, equal (a0, a1))                                        
            |> Set.add (false, equal (a1, b1))                                        
            |> evalClause m }
```

or this?

```
seq {
    for polarity, a in Set.filter (fun (polarity, _) -> polarity) c do
    let c = Set.remove (polarity, a) c
    for a0, a1 in orientations (eqn a) do
    for polarity, b in Set.filter (fun (polarity, _) -> polarity) c do
    let c = Set.remove (polarity, b) c
    for b0, b1 in orientations (eqn b) do
    match unify a0 b0 with
    | None ->
        ()
    | Some m ->
        yield 
            c                                            
            |> Set.add (true, equal (a0, a1))                                        
            |> Set.add (false, equal (a1, b1))                                        
            |> evalClause m 
}
```

And similarly for square brackets in list and array literals that are too large to be written on one line - is it usual to follow the same convention?

Comment: I've never seen the second brace style in any context, except perhaps for single-line brace constructs, as in `seq { all fits on one line }`  That said, F# is considered a functional language, and braces at the end of the last line appear to be acceptable, as in [here](https://github.com/dungpa/fantomas/blob/master/docs/FormattingConventions.md).

Comment: I don't think there is a generally accepted standard. Some F# authors I read use the first syntax, some use the second. I tend to do the latter to make it easier to add a line at the end, especially from pasting. Don't tell anyone, but I sometimes copy and paste. :)